# Выделить числа из строки в список

Tags: python

Как мне отсеять 2 числа в массив из строчки?

```
print('Tny6anxayna = 104 nognucunkos §—-29 noanucok')
```

Output:

```
[104,29]
```

Comment: Уточните, по какому принципу, `-29` должно отсеиваться как число, а `y6a` - нет? И как быть с тем, что `-29` это тоже число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте регулярками:

```py
import re
t = 'Tny6anxayna = 104 nognucunkos §—-29 noanucok'

p = re.compile("(\d*) ")
m = p.findall(t)
# m = ['', '', '104', '', '29']

ls = []
for i in m:
    if i != "":
        ls.append(i)
print(ls)
```

Возможно получится составить регулярку лучше чтобы не цепляла пробелы тогда можно будет убрать лишнюю конструкцию if но побыстрому получился такой вариант.

Comment: Чтобы "не цепляло пробелы" пробел можно вынести за скобку

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо поправил так можно убрать ненужный replace. Но имел ввиду пробелы в m после регулярки. P.S. Уже подсмотрел в Вашем ответе.

Comment: Ну да, лишние пустые строки можно убрать, заменив `\d*` на `\d+`

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понял принцип, но видимо так:

```
import re
text = 'Tny6anxayna = 104 nognucunkos §—-29 noanucok'

re_digits = re.compile(r"\b\d+\b")
print(re_digits.findall(text))
```

Вывод:

```
['104', '29']
```

Answer (score 0):

ну как вариант если строка нестандартная - заменить все символы на пробелы, потом сделать `split()` и выделить числа, правда в этом случае и для `5a7` получится 2 числа

например так:

```
text = 'Tny6anxayna = 104 nognucunkos §—-29 noanucok'

text_digits = ''.join(letter for letter in text if letter in ' \t0123456789')

print(text_digits.split())
```

правда тут лишняя `6` из `Tny6anxayna` вылезает :(

Comment: Про `-29` еще тоже сомнительно ..

Comment: @Kromster, это да, но если считать, что только натуральные числа надо вычленить...